# Regular Expression in put request

Tags: regex, reactjs

I'm posting keyless objects from a text area as a string from the body of a note / reminder.  The value of JSON.stringify is `{"":"text"}`

What is the regular expression to just return the word text.

Comment: Did you know that JSON stands for **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation? There is ZERO reason for regex here.

Comment: Read the duplicate. Once you use `JSON.parse()` then your answer is in `obj[""]`

Comment: terrible thing to do, but you could use something like this: https://regex101.com/r/F1DDZU/1/codegen?language=javascript